# For Loop That Starts At Middle Of Range And Loops Around

Tags: c++, c, loops, for-loop, range

Is it possible to have a for loop that starts at the middle of a range and then loops around to the beginning of the range and continues until it loops through the whole range?  For example, assuming we have a range of 0 to 63, I want the loop to start at 22, continue looping until it reaches 63, then start at 0 and loop until it reaches 21.  Is this possible with a for loop?  Or would I require a while loop?

Comment: It's doable in either a `for` loop or a `while` loop.  The two loop types are interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, use something like `i = (i+1) % length` to iterate.

Comment: What did you try? And why does it not work? There are several possible solutions, for example, you can simply use two loops, or add the offset and use the '%' operator, as 500-InternalServerError suggests, and I'm sure there are more ways.

Comment: You're looping 64 iterations, regardless of what your goal is.  So of course a `for` loop will work.

Comment: You can use some variant on: `int lo = 0; int hi = 63; int start = 22; for (int i = 0; i < (hi - lo + 1); i++) { int index = (start - lo + i) % (hi - lo + 1) + lo; …use index… }` which will work for your sequence, and also for a sequence where `lo = 27`, `hi = 41` and `start = 36` (producing 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35 if you simply print the value of `index` in the loop).  There are ways to do it without the loop variable `i`, but it's considerably harder to get the wrapping and terminating conditions correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use two loop variables: one to count the number of repetitions and one to handle the desired index. Like this:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 22; i < 64; ++i, j = (j + 1) % 64)
    // do something with j
```

Of course, in real code you'd replace the magic numbers (22, 64) with something that more clearly reflects the actual objects involved.

Comment: This works nicely while the lower bound of the range is `0` — as in the question.  If the lower bound is not zero, you have to do some more work recalculating `j`.

Comment: What is the modulo operator for? Harry wanted just normal for loop that starts at some middle index, wasn't he? for (int i = mid_index+1; i < arr_size+1; i++)
     {
            release_baloon_nr(the_array[i-1]);
    
     //reset iteration
     if (i == arr_size) { i = 0; }
     }

Comment: @TomeeNS: when is your loop going to terminate?  And your loop variable is 'off by one' from the desired value — witness your call `release_baloon_nr(the_array[i-1])` instead of using just `i` in the subscript.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler -- re: "if the lower bound is not zero" -- you're absolutely right: if the question was different, the answer might not be the same.

Comment: @TomeeNS -- `I` counts repetitions; the loop will execute 64 times. `j` is the index; it starts at 22, increases until it reaches 63, then wraps around to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a range-based `for` loop for this. A C++20 STL example (with `using namespace std::ranges`):

```
constexpr void foo(auto&& range) {
  auto middle = range.begin() + 22;
  auto parts = {subrange{middle, range.end()}, subrange{range.begin(), middle}};
  for (auto&& elem: parts | views::join) bar(elem);
}
```

Maybe there's a better looking way / library. With a proper API, it should be something like

```
constexpr void foo(auto&& range) {
  for (auto&& elem: range | drop(22) | chain(range | take(22))) bar(elem);
}
```

**Edit:** almost the same "proper API" can be found ready in [`ranges::v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)`::view` (`concat` here is an "unpipable" version of my imaginary `chain`):

```
constexpr void foo(auto&& range) {
    for (auto&& elem: concat(range | drop(22), range | take(22))) bar(elem);
}
```

Comment: Since your second snippet is showing a demo of a library that doesn't actually exist, it would be a good idea to describe the adaptors you're using that are not standard, in particular, `chain`. As for a library that does stuff like this, take a look at range-v3, which is what `std::ranges` is heavily inspired by.

Comment: @cigien added that (even found a ready range-v3 implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example:

```
for( int i = 22, max = 63, end = i-1 ; i!=-1 ; i=i==end?-1:i==max?0:i+1 )
{
    // do something with i
}
```